# How to override the method in parent class in django Generic view

Tags: python, django

I am using the class based generic views.

```
class MyView(UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
    success_url = "/test/list"
```

Now this is working fine.

But i want to make the parent class so that my all views inherit from it and define `success_url` there like this

```
class MyMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.success_url ="/test/list?myvar=true"
```

then

```
class MyView(UpdateView, MyMixin):
    model = MyModel
    success_url = "/test/list"
```

But my `success_url` is not overridden

Comment: That's because `success_url` is not an instance variable, but it could also have to do with your indentation. Please fix the indentation first.

Comment: That was just the typo. but how can i accomplish my task

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are not modifying an instance variable but a local variable by the same name.

Comment: you can do that through a MyMixin instance, something like : mymixin_inst.success_url = '/some/url/'

Comment: Can you write some with more example. i don't get it

Answer (score 0):

Like @phoenix suggested, in your class myView, create an instance of MyMixin as follows

```
class myview(updateview,MyMixin):
    myVar=MyMixin("a") #just an e.g
    print myVar.success_url
```

Output:
/test/list?myvar=true

Answer (score 0):

I would just do this.

```
class MyMixinView(object):

    def get_success_url(self):
        return "/test/list"

class ChildUpdateView(UpdateView, MyMixinView):
    model = MyModel
```

HTH..

Comment: I tried that it also didn't worked. It says no url to redirect. System could not get the url from it

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the `myMixin` before the `Updateview` because Updateview already has the get_success_url.

This should work

```
class MyMixin(object):
    def get_success_url(self):
        return "/test/list"

class MyView(MyMixin, UpdateView):
    model = MyModel
```